# Not able to Checkout Component or Page after adding Event Handler

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am adding event handler for **CheckOutEventArgs**, and am trying to get the checkout user details. Below is my code.

```cs
public void Subscribe()
{
    EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, CheckOutEventArgs>(PageCheckOutWarning,
                                                   EventPhases.Initiated);
    EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, CheckOutEventArgs>(ComponentCheckOutWarning,
                                                        EventPhases.Initiated);
} 

private void ComponentCheckOutWarning(Component component, 
                                      CheckOutEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{
    logdetails("Checkout User-->" + component.CheckOutUser.Title.ToString());
}
```

When I try to checkout the Component/Page I get this error in the Tridion Explorer error message box.

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have subscribed to `Initiated` phase, in this phse item is not checked out yet, hence no `CheckOutUser`. You should subscribe to some of the later phases.

Also, I don't know what your code is doing, but you might consider subscribing to some generic class, like `VersionedItem` that contains both component and page.

Again, not knowing your idea, but take a look at `SubscribeAsync` method if you want to have just warning. This way it will execute faster.

If you still want to know the user in the initiated phase - you can get it from session:
`component.Session.User.Title`

You can subscribe to VersionedItem and then in the event handler do:

```
private void CheckOutWarning(VersionedItem item, CheckOutEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{
    if (item.GetType().Name == "Component" || item.GetType().Name == "Page")
    {
    }
}
```

Do you want to have just warning, or do you want to prevent CheckOut?

Comment: VersionedItem will contain Templates as well. Instead of EventPhases.Initiated use EventPhases.Processed. Also add null check to component.CheckOutUser.

Comment: I want to give the warning message for the Page and Component at the time of checkedout. If the same revisor is checkedout the page/componet, then no issue, in case if the revisor and checkedout user is not same, then i have to show warning message. To acomplish this, i need to subscribe Component and Page right? or is there any way to do this in single subscribe? or is there any better way?

Comment: VersionedItem will cover Page, Component? and Can i use subscribe()? and am trying VersionedItem vitem = session.GetObject(page.Id) as VersionedItem;vitem.Revisor.Title; it is giving the current checkedout user details only. for current checkedout user i tried page.CheckOutUser.Title, but both are giving the same output

Comment: With regards to subscribing, I would subscribe to both Page and Component and call the generic method CheckOutWarning(VersionedItem item, CheckOutEventArgs args, EventPhases phase), this way you don't duplicate code and also not fire your code on all Check Out events of a VersionedItem.

Comment: You have already asked Revisor vs CheckOutUser in other question. If you want to just give warning - use `SubscrybeAsync`, if you want to prevent checkout, when user is not ok - use `Subscrybe`. VersionedItem will cover Schemas, Component, Pages and Templates. You may workaround it by the code I've provided in my answer, or even better follow Bart's advise

Comment: I just want the warning, if the revisor and checkedout user is different